# Beginner SQL trouble with simple Join/Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is a quite a basic query, but I can't find exactly the solution for my needs, so here goes...

I have a table of customers INT_AUX_LISTING, a table of folders in which they're contained INT_AUX_DIRECTORY and a joining table INT_AUX_DIR_LIST.

I need to return a list of all customers who are in folder 40017, and also not in folder 2. Any other folder in which they're contained is irrelevant.

So far I've come up with

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INT_AUX_LISTING l 
       LEFT JOIN INT_AUX_DIR_LIST dl 
                 ON l.LISTING_ID=dl.LISTING_ID
 WHERE dl.CONTAIN_DIR_ID=40017
   AND dl.CONTAIN_DIR_ID <> 2
```

However this (obviously) isn't correct, and is returning far too many values. I think I need to introduce a subquery but things go awry when I try.

Apologies for the entry level nature of the question, but it's only my 3rd day working with SQL!

Comment: Provide `CREATE` for your tables, please.

Comment: Not sure if this is the place to add comments, but I hope so. Customers can be contained in multiple folders. Hence, being in folder 40017 does not mean they are not necessary in folder 2. What I want to do is include those that are in 40017, and then remove those that are also not in folder 2.

Comment: This is easy question, all you need to do to get your answer is to provide `CREATE` for your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clarification on left-join and where.  If you have a query that has a left-join to a table (per your example where "dl" was the right-side of the join), and then add the "dl" alias to a where clause, that in essence converts it to an INNER JOIN (unless you explicitly tested with an OR dl.listing_ID IS NULL).

Now, back to your primary objective.  Without the table structures, and not exactly clear on your column intent, it APPEARS that the "listing_id" column is your client as found in the int_aux_listing table.  the "contain_dir_id" is the directory (one of many that may be possible) as found in the int_aux_dir_list.

That said, you want a list of all people who are in 40017 AND NOT in 2.  For this, you can do a left-join but using the int_aux_listing table twice but with different aliases.  Once you get the list of clients, you can then join that to your client table.  Since you are new, take the sample one step at a time.

Just get clients within 40017

```
select
      dl.listing_id
   from
      int_aux_dir_list dl
   where
      dl.contain_dir_id = 40017
```

Now, exclude those if they are found in directory 2

```
select
      dl.listing_id
   from
      int_aux_dir_list dl
         left join int_aux_dir_list dl2
            on dl.listing_id = dl2.listing_id
           AND dl2.contain_dir_id = 2
   where
          dl.contain_dir_id = 40017
      AND dl2.listing_id IS NULL
```

By doing a left-join to the directory listing table a second time (via alias "dl2"), but specifically for its directory id = 2 (via AND dl2.contain_dir_id = 2), you are getting all clients from dl that are within directory 40017 and looking for that same client ID in the second instance ("dl2").

Here's the kicker.  Notice the where clause is stating "AND dl2.listing_id IS NULL".

This is basically saying WHEN Looking at the DL2 instance, I only want records that DO NOT have a corresponding listing ID matched.

Now, wrap this up to get the client information you need.  In this case, getting all columns from the directory listing (in case other columns of importance), AND getting all columns from the "l"isting table.

```
select
      dl.*,
      l.*
   from
      int_aux_dir_list dl
         left join int_aux_dir_list dl2
            on dl.listing_id = dl2.listing_id
           AND dl2.contain_dir_id = 2
         join INT_AUX_LISTING l
            on dl.listing_id = l.listing_id
   where
          dl.contain_dir_id = 40017
      AND dl2.listing_id IS NULL
```

Hopefully this clears things up for you some.

Comment: Many thanks. I realise now I should show my tables in my question, although I'm sure there's a methodology I don't know about; the query I showed was edited to standardise it. Your assumptions about the table structures were correct, and your answer was correct.

Comment: @BenjKenj, take a look at the Help / Tour.  When you have an answer that solves your question, you should up vote if it was really good, and in addition, click the checkmark next to the answer so anyone else with similar issue, will know which worked as their guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is the problem; it brings back ALL rows except the one where that id is not 2, including the one where id is 40017 (since it's not equal to 2).  I think you should revisit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LEFT JOIN[[1]](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) on INT_AUX_LISTING, you will get all customers even if they don't have a corresponding folder. In your case it's best to use INNER JOIN[[2]](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) instead.

In the where clause, you're first statement selects customers who are in folder 40017 (dl.CONTAIN_DIR_ID=40017), because of this your second statement (dl.CONTAIN_DIR_ID <> 2) will always be true (40017 will never be equal to 2). So basically your selecting all customers in folder 40017.

Your notion of a subquery was correct. This is one way of getting the desired result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INT_AUX_LISTING l 
    INNER JOIN INT_AUX_DIR_LIST dl1 
        ON l.LISTING_ID = dl1.LISTING_ID
WHERE dl1.CONTAIN_DIR_ID = 40017
    AND l.LISTING_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT dl2.LISTING_ID FROM INT_AUX_DIR_LIST dl2 WHERE dl2.CONTAIN_DIR_ID = 2
    )
```

Comment: Changed final dl2.listing_id to contain_dir_id and it worked. Thanks!